# Powershell Determine Alphabetical Rank

Tags: string, powershell

I'm writing a script that creates user mailboxes, the problem is, we have two different databases depending on the user's last name.  First database is A-M, second is N-Z.  Based off of the first letter of a user's last name, how can I determine which side of the alphabet it's on to assign the database correctly?  For instance, I have

```
$DB = $LName[0]
```

That grabs the first letter of the last name, but from there, how do I determine if the string is above or below M?

Answer (score 2):

So, for some given string:

```
[int][char]'EBGreen'.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()
```

would give 69 which is the ASCII int for E. Compare this to 77 (ASCII int for M) to decide which DB to use.

Comment: Highlighting the importance of `.ToUpper()` to ensure you are dealing with one case and not have to worry about different codes for upper and lower case.

Comment: So it works if you type in the string manually, but it throws a system.char error if I try to use a variable I.E.   [int][char]$test.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()

Comment: @user3066571 the code you mention works for me on v3.0. What is your string? You could also try `[int][char]($test.Substring(0,1).ToUpper())` to ensure its trying to convert a single character as supposed to the whole string maybe?

Comment: What do you get for $test.GetType()?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Switch -Wildcard ($user.lastname)
{
 '[A-M]*' { $Database = 'DB1' }
 '[N-Z]*' { $Database = 'DB2' }
}
```

Comment: Should probably .ToUpper() the lastname just to be safe.

Comment: I tested, it and was case insensitive, but you can add the .ToUpper() if it helps you sleep better at night :).